# Application of centroid of body in real life

Tags: classical-mechanics

What is the practical application of centroid of the body whose centeroid lies out of it.
I know that we can balance a body at its centroid but what if lies out of that body?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we will need to deflect an oddly shaped asteroid heading towards Earth someday?

Comment: I understand that it is an hypothetica situation but then also if you can explain how centroid will be helpful in that situation will help me to understand the topic.